# external functions in Python 3.4

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

I have been working on an elements dictionary and I have encountered a problem with running external functions through inputs. I need to take an input and use it to call a function with several variables. here is my code:

```
import atoms
import time
print("Hello, and welcome to the element dictionary. This app takes an element symbol")
print(" and outputs a small amount of data about the element.")
element=input("please input an elements symbol :")
(element)
print('catagory: ',cat )
print(' atomic number: ',atomn)
print(' atomic weight: ',atomw)
print('colour: ',colour )
print(' phase: ',phase )
print(' melting point: ',meltpoint)
print('boiling point: ',boilpoint)
print('crystal structure: ',cstruc)
time.sleep(100)
```

`(element)` is where an external function is needed, and 'atoms' is where the functions are stored.

Comment: What do you mean by "external function"?

Comment: Please provide your whole code.

Comment: Are you just asking how to use a name from a module you imported? If you `import os`, you can call `os.listdir()`. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: @abarnert , Im looking to import from a file in a folder dedicated to this project

Comment: So… is that a yes? If not, you'll need to explain better. If so, your code shows that you already know how to call a function from `time`; what makes you think calling a function from `atoms` will be any different?

Comment: well I need the function to be inputted by the user

Comment: @DanAntcliffe You want the user to enter the function "name" or the complete "Python code" of the function ?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux , I need the user to input the function name

Answer (score 0):

> I need the function to be inputted by the user

I don't really know if this what you are looking for. But you have to know that Python has the so called [First-class function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function). That is, you may store a function in a variable like any other value. In a varaible or in a dictionary.

To familiarize yourself with that idea, take some time experimenting with this example:

```
def f():
    print("This is f")

def g():
    print("This is g")

def other():
    print("Other choice")

actions = {
   "f": f,
   "F": f,
   "g": g,
   "G": g
}

your_choice=raw_input("Choose f or g: ")
your_fct = actions.get(your_choice, other)
#                                   ^^^^^
#                                default value

your_fct()
```

Of course, you can pass arguments while calling `your_fct` just like any other function.